# How to fix "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when connecting Jupyter notebook on AWS ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, permission-denied

I am setting up ec2 on Aws for the first time. When I command to run Jupyter notebook, it runs and says no browser found. However, when I put the link to connect Jupyter through my browser, I see this message in my browser--

```
This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I tried several times to connect with Chrome and Firefox. But, haven't got connected. When I try to connect through Firefox, it shows the following message-

```
Secure Connection Failed

The connection to ec2-18-224-212-245.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888 was interrupted while the page was loading.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

After putting command - jupyter notebook - it runs but shows the browser not found error

```
[I 14:45:00.935 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 14:45:00.935 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 14:45:00.936 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

when i try to connect the jupyter notebook through my browser this error shows up

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am expecting my Jupyter notebook run and load in browser. So that, I can use my Aws Jupyter notebook.